# Wavefunction spinor in Dirac equation

Tags: special-relativity, wavefunction, quantum-spin, dirac-equation, spinors

Which is the physical interpretation that in Dirac's equation the wavefunction is a spinor?

Comment: Why dont you go and read up a proper textbook? These things are covered properly in standard texts

Comment: Sadly I am not a Physics major.

Comment: That is fine; there are plenty of physics textbooks covering this that you can borrow, or even freely read online.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent The Stack Exchange site has a "be nice" policy which is not what I think you're doing.  It would be more practical to e.g. find a suitable duplicate question or even to post a simple two or three line answer than to just refer them to a library where they'll likely just get lost.  "Read a physics textbook" would surely be a comment anyone could make to any question on the site.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine you should look at the other questions appliedSciences already put on the site to see what is actually the problem at hand.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Most of the existing answers to similar do seem rather abstract to me.  I think the OP is looking for an intuitive sense of what a spinor is in the context of the Dirac equation.  I think a good answer to that would be useful.  The OP's previous questions suggest they're trying to run before they can walk, which is frankly normal in humans.

Comment: @appliedSciences not being a physics major is a curable condition (you clearly have some physics interest) - but I don't know your life and don't intend to influence your decision making. But even for non-physics majors, textbooks contain the most complete and clear descriptions of things like this, and they remain the best way to get a proper understanding.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning for experts**: this answer is (I think appropriately) mathematically imprecise and handwavy

Two ways I can think of to answer this question - the fact that there are four independent degrees of freedom corresponds to the fact that there are four ways to have an electron in a single spatial wavefunction - it can be an electron, a positron, spin up, and spin down ($2\times2$). That doesn't mean, however, that each component can be physically interpreted as "the spin up electron part, the spin down electron part, the spin up positron part, and the spin down positron part." And in fact the correspondence between the components and those four types of wavefunctions (as a function of momentum) depends on the "representation" you choose. And there is no representation where a spin up electron can be represented as solely one component of the spinor for all electron wavefunctions.

On the other hand, you can think of the spinor as a representation of the Lorentz group. This is fancy group theory speak for the following physical argument: it seems clear that the laws of physics don't change for different inertial reference frames, and that special relativity gives a correct description of how to move between reference frames. Thus the wavefunction of a particle in a fully relativistic description of quantum mechanics must have some reasonable and well-defined way it changes when you do a Lorentz transformation. These different cogent ways of changing under a Lorentz transformation are called "representations of the Lorentz group." For each representation of the Lorentz group we find a new type of particle that could exist. To list a few, we have vectors (which transform just like momentum does in special relativity), scalars (which don't change at all when you do a lorentz transformation), and spinors. And then the fact that spinors have four components is just because the spinor representation of the lorentz group has four components.

Comment: That sounds about as simplified as you can get while still getting some reasonable depth to it.  Nice.